# How does one create Razor Page Urls in C# code?

Tags: c#, razor-pages

Microsoft introduced [Razor Pages](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/razor-pages/?view=aspnetcore-2.1&tabs=visual-studio) in ASP.NET Core 2.0 as an alternative to MVC. We are looking to migrate our legacy ASP.NET MVC 5 app to NET Core and Microsoft recommends using Razor Pages instead of MVC moving forward.

We are currently using [T4MVC](https://github.com/T4MVC/T4MVC) framework to help generate strongly-typed ActionResult objects to construct complex navigation menus. The nav menu is created using a viewmodel which is a linked list of ActionResult routes where each route can be something quite complex such as:

https://example.com/Client/1/Documents/2/Edit?p1=123&p2=ABC&h2=456

In T4MVC I can add this controller action to my viewmodel with:

```
menu.Add(MVC.Client.Documents.Edit(cliendId, documentId, requestParameters));
```

The ASP documentation doesn't go into detail on how to create routes in code, other than a simple: RedirectToPageResult("./Index") so how does one build more complex page routes without the benefit of T4MVC or resorting to magic strings?

Comment: *Microsoft recommends using Razor Pages instead of MVC moving forward* That seems odd. I see Razor Pages as a lightweight version of MVC, based on MVC. It is not a replacement.

Comment: See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-mvc-app/?view=aspnetcore-2.1 in particular "Is the preferred approach for new application development"

Comment: Isn't that covered by https://learn.microsoft.com/aspnet/core/tutorials/razor-pages/search as in: no additional wiring needed?

Comment: The docs pages cover quite simple scenarios where the routes are all relative and the query params or handler / action can be set within the view. Our application is way more complex. It is a multi-tenancy, multi-purpose CMS system and each page can have multiple nav menus and other context menus. The routes carry across context parameters allowing users to switch to different application areas and come back again. We generate the nav menus using builders which take a context object and generate a menu. So right now this is coordinated by the controller, not by the view.

Comment: MS seems to be implying that any type of application can be build using Razor Pages. We think not, but we are willing to give it a go. Some discussion here https://github.com/aspnet/Docs/issues/6146

Answer (score 0):

You can easily hard code the URL if you know the name of the path of the razor page relative to the Pages folder(this is by default).For example:

```
 public IActionResult OnPostGoogle(string provider)
        {

            var redirectUrl = "https://localhost:5001/UserPages/ExternalLoginCallback";
            var properties = signInManager.ConfigureExternalAuthenticationProperties(provider, redirectUrl);
            return new ChallengeResult(provider, properties);
        }
```

This is a method that configure Google login and redirects user to ExternalLoginCallback page.
Here I have ExternalLoginCallback.cshtml.cs that is in Pages/UserPages.
So you can append a relative path to your page from PagesFolder to your website address or in my case localhost and you will get full url to your page.That is why they used in example RedirectToPageResult("./Index")  because Index.cshtml.cs is directly in Pages folder.